# Data import from MySQL with Apache Sqoop - Error : No manager for connect string

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to integrate Mahout with an External Datasource. I'm following the [Apache Mahout Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/apache-mahout-cookbook/book) book for that.

I have configured Hadoop 2.4, MySQL server and I have imported a dummy database into mysql.

I have also installed Apache Sqoop following the steps in the book and I have downloaded and deployed mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar in the Sqoop library (sqoop/lib)

I've built sqoop with ant command :

```
   ant mvn-install
```

The build goes fine.

I'm trying to import data from mysql using the following command as described in the book :

```
   sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql/localohost/bbdatabank --username root -P --verbose
```

But it's failing with following error :

```
Warning: /usr/lib/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
14/05/05 14:19:29 DEBUG tool.BaseSqoopTool: Enabled debug logging.
Enter password:
14/05/05 14:19:30 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
14/05/05 14:19:30 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
14/05/05 14:19:30 DEBUG manager.DefaultManagerFactory: Trying with scheme: jdbc
14/05/05 14:19:30 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager:
java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string: jdbc:mysql/localohost/bbdatabank
      at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:185)
      at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:225)
      at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.init(ImportTool.java:84)
      at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportAllTablesTool.run(ImportAllTablesTool.java:82)
      at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
      at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
      at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
      at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
      at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
      at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

*Can someone please help me find what I am missing? Why is this error being produced and how can I solve it?*

**PS :** I haven't installed HBase nor HCatalog cause the book says that I don't need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your jdbc url is incorrect, it should be like

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/bbdatabank
```

Comment: I have tried also jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:bbdatabank/ setting up the port but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Are you getting the same exception or exception changed ?. BTW.. URL with port number is. jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bbdatabank/